# Xslt Insert Image From Path

Tags: xslt

I have a xslt file and i want add an image from path. I tried with this codes but i didn't see image in my xslt file.

My codes:

```
 <td width="40%" align="right" valign="middle">
       <br/>
       <img style="width:400px;" align="right" alt="Barcode"
       src="file:///C:/DCS/DCSEInvoiceBarcode.png"/>
 </td>
```

And my result is here:

[image]

What is the problem in my code and what must do i?

Thank you.

Comment: You haven't posted any XSLT code at all, just some HTML or XHTML. And it seems your "result" shows at least one image. So how do you look at the result, where it is rendered? Have you looked, if it is a browser, with F12 at the developer console for errors/warnings that a file could not be found or loaded?

Comment: I send xslt file to Turkish Goverments invoice service.  the picture in my message is my result. I'm not see any other problem in this document.

Comment: You are uploading the XSLT to some server or webservice? What does the server or webservice return, a HTML document? A PDF?

Comment: An how do you render the result, in a web browser?

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I posted with web service this xslt file. I recieve my picture from service provider company's web interface.

Comment: So what file format/MIME type/content type does the result from the service have, is it a PDF, a PNG, a JPEG document, a HTML document?

Comment: After we post the service our object, we can download xml, xslt and PDF formats.

Answer (score 0):

Solved our problem.
When we searched, we found that: Our codes is correct. The problem's source is invoice provider company's service. If you need insert picture from path to xslt, you can use this codes:

```
 <td width="40%" align="right" valign="middle">
       <br/>
       <img style="width:400px;" align="right" alt="Barcode"
       src="file:///C:/DCS/DCSEInvoiceBarcode.png"/>
 </td>
```

Comment: Posting the same code you showed in the question now as the "solution" to the question doesn't seem to explain anything.